# Fill data from JSON into select box using DOJO

Tags: dojo

I am working on loading JSON data and fill it on select tag

I am using DOJO for this, and i have to use dojo,

please tell me what is wrong

The problem which i am facing is , in JSON GetStatesResult is used to declare array
but it doesn't work, **it works only if i use items in place of GetStatesResult**

```
dojo.ready(function() {
                    var stateStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
                        url : "http://localhost:8080/MobilePro/states.json"
                    });
                    function completed(GetStatesResult) {
                        var ref = dom.byId("stateSelect");
                        for ( var i = 0; i < GetStatesResult.length; i++) {
                            var node = domConstruct.create("option", {value: stateStore.getValue(GetStatesResult[i], "Value"), label: stateStore.getValue(GetStatesResult[i], "Desc")});
                            domConstruct.place(node, ref, "last");
                        }
                    }
                    function error(errData, request) {
                        console.log("Failed in loading data.");
                    }
                    stateStore.fetch({
                        onComplete : completed,
                        onError : error
                    });
                });
```

This is the JSON

```
{
    "GetStatesResult": [
        {
            "Desc": "--Select--",
            "Value": "-1"
        },
        {
            "Desc": "Alaska",
            "Value": "AK"
        },
        {
            "Desc": "Alabama",
            "Value": "AL"
        },
        {
            "Desc": "Arkansas",
            "Value": "AR"
        },
        {
            "Desc": "Arizona",
            "Value": "AZ"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: By the way `dojo` is obsolete and the community doesn't work on it so you should also move to `struts-2 ajax plugin`

Comment: This is not struts project It is complete html5 with css and dojo where we need to utilize external server

Comment: I'm not a big Dojo fan, but it IS being actively developed. They just released 1.8 last year (up to 1.8.3 now) and are working on 2.0.

Comment: The dojo toolkit is NOT obsolete, and is actively developed.  I believe @pKs is referring to a dojo plugin specific to struts.

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using?

Comment: @CraigSwing yep I was referring to struts dojo and not the dojo toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

ItemFileReadStore requires that the list of items be in a property called "items". It's hardcoded its source code:

```
this._arrayOfTopLevelItems = dataObject.items;
```

If you're only using the ItemFileReadStore to fetch the items, why not just use dojo.xhrGet()? And if you really want to use an ItemFileReadStore, the user dojo.xhrGet() to retrieve the data, put it in the right format (use the items property), then pass it into the ItemFileReadStore constructor using the data property. Something like:

```
dojo.xhrGet({ url: "whatever", success: function(response) {
   var data = {items: response.GetStatesResult};
   var stateStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: data});
});
```

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood what you were describing. You're saying that it works when "GetStatesResult" is replaced with "items" in the JSON? I'll update my answer.